# Remove participants based on a certain criteria

Tags: r, filtering, subset, data-manipulation

I have an experiment with numerous participants and their choices. 
For simplicity, let's assume the following:

```
part<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
choice<-c(6,2,9,2,3,18,3,6,8)
study<-cbind(part,choice)

       part choice
 [1,]    1      6
 [2,]    1      2
 [3,]    1      9
 [4,]    2      2
 [5,]    2      3
 [6,]    2     18
 [7,]    3      3
 [8,]    3      6
 [9,]    3      8
```

Now, I would like to **entirely** remove certain participants. For example those who made at least one choice above 10. So in the example above, because participant 2, made one choice above 10, I entirely remove him: The final data should look:

```
      part choice
[1,]    1      6
[2,]    1      2
[3,]    1      9
[4,]    3      3
[5,]    3      6
[6,]    3      8
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do `study %>%
 group_by(part) %>%
 filter(all(choice < 10))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
 study %>% 
   group_by(part) %>% 
   filter(max(choice)<10)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   part [2]
   part choice
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      6
2     1      2
3     1      9
4     3      3
5     3      6
6     3      8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
removed = which(study[ , 2]>10);
study = study[!(study[ , 1] %in% study[removed, 1]), ];

study
     part choice
[1,]    1      6
[2,]    1      2
[3,]    1      9
[4,]    3      3
[5,]    3      6
[6,]    3      8
```

with this code you don't even need to install any package.

Answer (score 1):

Using R base, without need of loading packages. The example uses variable names, instead of position, for better overview of the solution.

```
# Create object to be used in dataframe.
part   <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
choice <- c(6,2,9,2,3,18,3,6,8)
# Create dataframe.
study  <- data.frame(part, choice)

# Find rows in column [study$choice]
find_rows <- which(study$choice > 10)
# Find participant that matches [find_rows]
participant_to_be_deleted <- study[find_rows,1]

# Remove all rows that has found participant in [study$part].
result <- study[study$part!=participant_to_be_deleted,]
```